# In C#, what is wrong with my negative test of TryAsync?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, moq, xunit

I have the following method:

```
public TryAsync<bool> TryRelay(
    MontageUploadConfig montageData,
    File sourceFile,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken
) => new(async () =>
{
    byte[] fileContent = await _httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(sourceFile.Url, cancellationToken);
    return await _attachmentController.TryUploadAttachment(montageData.EventId, fileContent, sourceFile.Name);
});
```

I created a couple tests to prove it works as expected.
My test for a negative case is failing.

This is the test:

```
[Fact]
public static async Task TestRelayShouldCatchErrorsGettingFile()
{
    // Arrange
    Mock<IAttachmentControllerV6> mockAttachmentController = new();
    Mock<HttpMessageHandler> mockHttpMessageHandler = new();
    MontageUploadTaskProcessor mockProcessorUnderTest = CreateProcessor(mockAttachmentController, mockHttpMessageHandler);

    MontageUploadConfig montageData = new()
    {
        EventId = "Test001"
    };
    File sourceFile = new()
    {
        Name = "Test.pdf",
        Url = "https://www.example.com/test.pdf"
    };
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default;

    const string message = "Expected Exception";
    mockHttpMessageHandler.SetupAnyRequest()
        .Throws(new SalesforceCacheException(message));

    // Act
    Result<bool> result = await mockProcessorUnderTest.TryRelay(montageData, sourceFile, cancellationToken)();

    // Assert
    Assert.True(result.IsFaulted);
    result.IfFail(exception =>
    {
        Assert.True(exception is Exception);
        Assert.Equal(message, exception.Message);
    });
}
```

This is the error:

> WorkflowTests.TaskProcessor.OldOrg.MontageUploadTaskProcessorUnitTests.TestRelayShouldCatchErrorsGettingFile
> Source: MontageUploadTaskProcessorUnitTests.cs line 59    Duration:
> 144 ms
>
> Message:  SFCacheController.SalesforceCacheException : Expected
> Exception
>
> Stack Trace:  ThrowException.Execute(Invocation invocation) line 22
> MethodCall.ExecuteCore(Invocation invocation) line 97
> Setup.Execute(Invocation invocation) line 85
> FindAndExecuteMatchingSetup.Handle(Invocation invocation, Mock mock)
> line 107 IInterceptor.Intercept(Invocation invocation) line 17
> Interceptor.Intercept(IInvocation underlying) line 107
> AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
> HttpMessageHandlerProxy.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request,
> HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean
> emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken) <b__0>d.MoveNext() line
> 140
> --- End of stack trace from previous location --- MontageUploadTaskProcessorUnitTests.TestRelayShouldCatchErrorsGettingFile()
> line 81
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---

The exception seems to be thrown after `TryRelay()` is invoked, but even before any assertions are attempted.

Am I wrong to expect `TryAsync` will catch and box the exception?
Am I wrong to expect this to work in a test context?
What do I need to do to make this test pass?

Comment: Doesn't this answer you got and accepted recently (https://stackoverflow.com/a/69358330/5311735) discusses exactly this same problem?

Comment: It discusses the problem, but somewhere between there are trying to actually create a unit test to prove the functionality and prevent regressions, I realized I'm missing something... I expect it is on the testing side.

Comment: You still use the wrong approach (`new(async () => ...`) to create TryAsync, you are not using function `LanguageExt.Prelude.TryAsync` provided by the library for that.

Comment: I thought I changed that... will try again, thanks.  :-)

Comment: @Evk, that was the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're directly invoking the `TryAsync`, it's just a function, and so it won't catch anything unless you use the extensions on `TryAsync`, like `Match`

What you could do is build a helper extension for your unit tests:

```
public static Task<bool> HasFailed<E, A>(this TryAsync<A> ma) where E : Exception =>
    ma.Match(Succ: _ => false,
             Fail: e => e is E);
```

Then you can write:

```
TryAsync<X> ma = ...;

Assert.True(await ma.HasFailed<IOException, X>());
```

Comment: louthster,  thanks for the response, but @Evk already diagnosed the problem: I need to use `LanguageExt.Prelude.TryAsync` so it _will_ do the catch.   (`Match` is already dealing with the result, which is too late.)

Comment: I'm the author of language-ext, so I kinda know what I'm talking about here ;)  

That's only partially correct.  The line has a `()` at the end, it's invoking the TryAsync delegate, which you shouldn't do, even if it works in this case, it's not guaranteed to work in every case.  The recommended way is to Match or use IfSucc/IfFail.

You're also working directly with `Result<A>` which is not the recommended way to use Try or TryAsync: https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/blob/main/LanguageExt.Core/Common/Result/Result.cs#L25

Comment: `Result<A>` will probably be deprecated (or at least have its API surface deprecated), as it encourages exactly what you're trying here, and can lead to messy outcomes, and also possible uncaught exceptions.  I've been trying to work out how to do it with the least impact, but it will go away.  So, for long term maintainability of your code, use the extension methods.

I don't know how far into your lang-ext journey you are, but if you want sync/async side-effects to be managed even better, then I'd advise using the Aff and Eff monads instead of TryAsync and Try.

Comment: They don't have any of the issues of `Try` and `TryAsync`, and are much more powerful for dealing with side-effects:

https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/wiki/How-to-deal-with-side-effects

Comment: Cheers for all the info!  I'm just at the beginning of my journey into lang-ext.  I'll need to look into `Aff` and `Eff`... not the most intuitive names.

Comment: `Eff` - short for Effect (or side-effect), `Aff` - short for asynchronous side-effect.  They're much more powerful than simple try/catch of `Try`, so the names reflect that.  

The names are inspired by `Eff` and `Aff` from PureScript and Haskell world.  They also have analogues in other languages, like ZIO in Scala.